# INSERT INTO in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, db2

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a INSERT INTO statement within a CASE statement in SQL code.

Here's a rough pseudocode of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT (CASE (SELECT SomeValue FROM SomeTable)
            WHEN NULL THEN
                INSERT INTO OtherTable VALUES (1, 2, 3)
                (SELECT NewlyInsertedValue FROM OtherTable)
            ELSE
                (SELECT SomeOtherValue FROM WeirdTable)
        END),
       Column1,
       Column2
FROM BigTable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to accomplish with `IF...THEN` statements instead.  Something roughly like this (not sure about syntax for db2):

```
SELECT @SomeValue = SomeValue FROM SomeTable

IF @SomeValue IS NULL
    INSERT INTO OtherTable VALUES (1, 2, 3)
    SELECT NewlyInsertedValue FROM OtherTable;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO OtherTable VALUES (1, 2, 3)
    SELECT SomeOtherValue FROM WeirdTable;
END IF;
```

Comment: That's the problem. I'm not sure how to replicate something like that in DB2

Comment: Um.. Start with the documentation??  I've given you a plausible structure for your code to do what you're trying to do.  You can dig into the specifics of the exact syntax.  I know this structure would work in SQL Server or MySql.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it two statements like so.

First insert into `other` when `somevalue is null`

```
INSERT INTO othertable 
SELECT 1, 
       2, 
       3 
FROM   bigtable 
WHERE  somevalue IS NULL;
```

Then left join to both tables on `Somevalue` being `null` or `not null`

```
SELECT Coalesce(othertable.newlyinsertedvalue, weirdtable.someothervalue) foo, 
       column1, 
       column2 
FROM   bigtable 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN othertable 
         ON somevalue IS NULL 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN weirdtable 
         ON somevalue IS NOT NULL
```

My guess is that you will actually have to modify the joins to be something like

```
       LEFT OUTER JOIN othertable 
         ON somevalue IS NULL 
           and bigtable.id = othertable.id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN weirdtable 
         ON somevalue IS NOT NULL 
           and bigtable.id = weirdtable .id
```

Note: I'm not sure what the DB2 equivalent of Coalesce is