# How to execute INSERT commands in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case-statement, insert-statement

I have 3 tables A, B, C. I have two different INSERT statements to insert into these three tables. I want to have a case statement which will decide which INSERT statement will run for which table depending on some condition. How do i put a case for this.

lIke --
Consider table driving_table--
table_name  table_type
A           STATIC
B           STATIC
C           DYNAMIC

Now i want to have a case which gives INSERT statemnt 1 when table_type =  static or INSERT statement 2 when table_type= DYNAMIC

Comment: CASE is an expression in t-sql. It controls what is returned for a single value in a select statement. It is NOT intended to control flow of statements. For that you need to use IF statements instead.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Sean, using IF statement worked. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996591/insert-into-in-a-case-statement